# PyAutoGui при поиске картинки нажимает куда-то, где картинки нет

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании PyAutoGui. Я задал ему несколько картинок, которые он должен найти и нажать на то место, где они находятся. Проблема заключается в том, что он нажимает в точку на экране, на которой указанной картинки нет.

```
import time
import pyautogui
import os
import subprocess
time.sleep(5)
if (pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Script\Update\battlenet_button_continue.png', confidence=0.5) is not None):
    bnetcontinuelocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Script\Update\battlenet_button_update.png', confidence=0.5)
    bnetcontinuepoint = pyautogui.center(bnetcontinuelocation)
    bnetcontinuex, bnetcontinuey = bnetcontinuepoint
    pyautogui.click(bnetcontinuex, bnetcontinuey)
time.sleep(5)
if (pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Script\Update\battlenet_button_stop.png', confidence=0.5) is not None):
    bnetstoplocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Script\Update\battlenet_button_stop.png', confidence=0.5)
    bnetstoppoint = pyautogui.center(bnetstoplocation)
    bnetstopx, bnetstopy = bnetstoppoint
    pyautogui.click(bnetstopx, bnetstopy)
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(bnetstopx, bnetstopy)
time.sleep(5)
print("Готово")
```

Пытался менять параметр confidence, добавлять grayscale и это не помогает.

[image: C:\Script\Update\battlenet_button_update.png]

[image: C:\Script\Update\battlenet_button_stop.png]

Вот эти 2 изображения. Используются они в лаунчере battle.net при нажатии на данную кнопку [image: Кнопка в лаунчере]
С другими картинками работает корректно. Также пробовал перескринить эти "кнопки", но на результат это не повлияло.